# Public variable returns empty string

Tags: vba, global-variables

I am creating a document using VBA at work (because that is the only thing I can use at work). My variable is returning an empty string after it is set. I am trying to pass data to a a user form from a method hat is dynamically generated at runtime.

I set the variable like so at the top of the ThisDocument module

```
Public theName As String
```

Then I run this when a checkbox is checked

```
With tblNew
    '.Cell(Row:=rowCount, Column:=2).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(Row:=rowCount, Column:=3)
    .Rows(rowCount).SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(0.35), HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly
    .Cell(Row:=rowCount, Column:=1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(0.75), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    .Cell(Row:=rowCount, Column:=2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(2.08), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    .Cell(Row:=rowCount, Column:=3).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(1), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    .Cell(Row:=rowCount, Column:=4).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(2), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    .Cell(Row:=rowCount, Column:=5).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(1.85), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    .Cell(rowCount, 1).Range.InsertAfter "Name:"
    .Cell(rowCount, 3).Range.InsertAfter "Type:"
    .Cell(rowCount, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1"
  Set myCB = .Cell(rowCount, 4).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1")
        Dim uofCode As String
        Dim doc As Word.Document

        Set doc = ActiveDocument

        theName = myCB.OLEFormat.Object.Name
        MsgBox theName ‘this message works fine
            uofCode = "Private Sub " & myCB.OLEFormat.Object.Name & "_GotFocus()" & vbCrLf & _
             vbCr & "Load uofForm" & vbCr & "uofForm.Tag = theName" & vbCr & "uofForm.Show" & vbCr & vbCrLf & _
            "End Sub"
            doc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString uofCode

             End With
```

I set the variable `theName` with this line `theName = myCB.OLEFormat.Object.Name` and make sure it's set for testing with a MsgBox `MsgBox theName` This message works fine. Now the problem is when it generates the function the variable is empty. Any ideas why the variable `theName` is not staying set?

Comment: I have a feeling that your `& "uofForm.Tag = theName" & ` is just a convoluted way of achieving `& "uofForm.Tag = """ & myCB.OLEFormat.Object.Name & """" & `.  (My guess as to why your variable isn't staying set is that some changes to code reset variables, so your code addition is probably the cause.  You could try moving the `theName = myCB.OLEFormat.Object.Name` line after you update the code and see what happens.)

Answer (score 2):

You're dynamically adding a sub routine to the *same* module at run-time. That will trigger a reset of the project - Ending program execution, and clearing all variables.

If you try manually adding a procedure to a running module (in debug mode), you'll get this warning:

[image]

But you don't get that warning when adding the code programmatically.

In any case, you're adding the procedure to the `ThisWorkbook` module, when you probably want to add it to the module of the sheet upon which the control is hosted.

Comment: Then how can you store data if you are adding the procedure at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try declare your variable as Global instead of Public like this

```
Global theName As String
```